# Update query hanging

Tags: sql-server

I have to update a table that has around 1.45 million records

Table schema:

```
ID bigint ,
LOADED_FILE_ID bigint ,
ENTRY_STATUS smallint
```

ID and LOADED_FILE_ID are the primary key and are indexed.

There are no triggers on this table.

I have 2 records in these 1.45 million records which have the same LOADED_FILE_ID=66 but when i try to update them the query hangs.

```
UPDATE TBLNAME SET ENTRY_STATUS=1 where LOADED_FILE_ID=66
```

Anyone got any idea why this hangs?

P.S.: The select query with the same where clause executes in an instant.

Comment: Is there an index with LOADED_FILE_ID as the first column? If your clustered index has ID first it won't be useful for finding LOADED_FILE_ID.

Comment: Also, could you please post the plan?

Comment: Check for blocking. The combination of other concurrent queries using the table and lack of a useful index can cause these symptoms. You mentioned `ID` and `LOADED_FILE_ID` are the primary key but that composite key index is not useful to this query because `LOADED_FILE_ID` is not the leftmost column. Without creating another index, you could add `ID` to the `WHERE clause` and execute 2 separate updates.

Comment: As @OwlsSleeping suggested, can you post the actual execution plan (https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and share the link.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, as it turned out there was a cursor that was kept opened from another process and it was blocking the table in general.

The query worked as intended today with no problems.

Thank you all for taking the time to answer.